# Max function in multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

Cannot get the maximum value of state per project
The only I get is all states from one to last, in the list. that output

```
| idState  | idProject |
| -------- | -------------- |
| 1        | 1              |
| 2        | 1              |
| 3        | 1              |
| 4        | 1              |
| 1        | 2              |
| 2        | 2              |
```

and so on.
What I need is

```
| idState  | idProject |
| -------- | -------------- |
| 4        | 1              |
| 2        | 2              |
```

Where State is the maximum value from the column per project

```
SELECT e.idState, e.delivery, ep.idProject
FROM State e
CROSS JOIN StatexProject ep ON e.idState = ep.idState
WHERE ep.idProject = (SELECT MAX(exp.idState) FROM StatexProject exp
WHERE ep.idState = exp.idState);
```

Comment: Have you tried `group by` and `max()`?

Comment: Group by, at the end of query, change nothning, Max() is on select, cause, every project must show the maximum value of state

Comment: Why are you trying to use a cross join?

Comment: I tried INNER also, but same, no change

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show sample table data and sample desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for basic aggregation (max per group). Your reply to Gordon's question in the comments doesn't make sense given your expected output. Give this a try and we can go from there

```
SELECT max(e.idState) as idState, ep.idProject
FROM State e
JOIN StatexProject ep ON e.idState = ep.idState
GROUP BY ep.idProject;
```

Comment: Can't believe, in the book that I read, is the query that I tried to do, but it'S not good result, your result is good, so I must write a letter to the autor of that book? =))